# Angular query params like httpd_query_params

Tags: php, angular, http, query-string

I'm currently using an API with functionnal tests. So I know that I'll have a good response with the url bellow :

```
/api/v1/investisseurs?vehicule%5B0%5D=4
```

Equivalent url decoded

```
/api/v1/investisseurs?vehicule[0]=4
```

Using Angular to emit my call with `HttpParams` like follow

```
getInvestors(params: HttpParams): Promise<MelodiiaCollectionResponse> {
    console.log(params);
    return <Promise<MelodiiaCollectionResponse>>this.http.get(environment.httpdBackHost + '/investisseurs', {
       params: params,
}).toPromise();
```

This result with the following request in my browser

```
/api/v1/investisseurs?vehicule%5B%5D=%5B%222%22%5D&page=1&max_per_page=15
```

Equivalent url decoded

```
/api/v1/investisseurs?vehicule[]=["2"]&page=1&max_per_page=15
```

Question, how it is possible to have the same query parameter encoding as the php method `http_build_query` within Angular 7?

I would like avoid reimplement the wheel myself :)

Thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpParams` builder to automatically parse your params by chaining *append* method. And with some reducers you can provide array values in your httpParams

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

//Whatever...

getInvestors(vehicules: number[], page: number, maxPerPage: number): Promise<MelodiiaCollectionResponse> {
  const params = vehicules.reduce(
    (previous, vehicule, index) => previous.append(`vehicule[${index}]`, vehicule.toString()),
     new HttpParams()
   )
   .append('max_per_page', maxPerPage.toString())
   .append('page', page.toString())
  return this.http.get<MelodiiaCollectionResponse>(`${environment.httpdBackHost}/investisseurs`, {
     params,
  }).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: I'll test your answer asap, and then come back to you. Thank :)

Comment: De rien mon cher ;)